# All possible combinations of portfolio weights

Tags: python, list, combinations, portfolio

I am looking for tips and tricks to better code the following in Python (e.g. remove superfluous loops and copying, use more splicing)

I have coded this to create all possible combinations of weights for a portfolio of N securities subject to the constraints:

Weights come from a list of possibilities (in this case 0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5)
The sum of weights for a valid portfolio must = 1 (Fully Invested)

This is not a valid approach as the number of combinations quickly becomes unmanageable. It's just me trying to get to grips with this language.

Thank you all in advance for you help!

```
import copy as cp

def generateWeights (weights,possibleWeights,N):
    "Generate all possible combinations of weights"
    # cycle over number of desired coloumns
    for i in range(0,N):
        # copy weights to iterate over every element while i pop stuff out of
        # the original list
        weightsCopy = cp.deepcopy(weights)
        for w in weightsCopy:
            # make a copy to edit
            wtemp = cp.deepcopy(w)
            for p in possibleWeights:
                # append every possibility 
                wtemp.append(p)
                # I only want combinations with sum == 1 so I can start
                # avoiding those that are > 1
                if sum(wtemp) <= 1:
                    weights.append(cp.deepcopy(wtemp))
                # get the original wtemp back so I can work on it with my next p
                wtemp.pop()
            # finished developing the first line of the table. Pop it out and
            # move on.
            weights.pop(0)
    # once again copy weights to iterate over every element while I edit the 
    # original list
    weightsCopy = cp.deepcopy(weights)        
    for w in weightsCopy:
        # remove all possibilities whose sum < 1
        # all those > 1 were never added
        if sum(w) < 1:
            weights.remove(w)
    return weights

N=6 # Number of securities
possibleWeights = [0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]
# weights is a coloumn because I want to access its elements and still get
# lists instead of floats.
weights = [[0.0],[0.1],[0.2],[0.3],[0.4],[0.5]]
weights = generateWeights(weights,possibleWeights,N)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the itertools module that already has the algorithms to do most of what you want.

```
from itertools import combinations

def valid_combinations(weights):
    '''generator of possible combinations of weights elements that add up to 1'''
    list_length = len(weights) # we will need this
    for lengths in range(list_length):
        for possible in combinations(weights, lengths): # all possible orderings of weights
            if sum(possible[:lengths]) == 1: # only generate valid ones
                yield possible[:lengths]


>>> original = [0, .1, .2, .3, .4, .5]
>>> print list(valid_combinations(original))
[(0.1, 0.4, 0.5), (0.2, 0.3, 0.5), (0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5), (0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5), (0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4), (0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4)]
```

If you are only interested in unique combinations of the weights (the order does not matter), you need to use `combinations`, if it does matter you should use `permutations` the following way:

```
from itertools import permutations

def valid_combinations(weights):
    '''generator of possible combinations of weights elements that add up to 1'''
    list_length = len(weights) # we will need this
    for possible in permutations(weights): # all possible orderings of weights
        for lengths in range(list_length): # get all prefix sublists
            if sum(possible[:lengths]) == 1: # only generate valid ones
                yield possible[:lengths]


>>> original = [0, .1, .2, .3, .4, .5]
>>> print list(valid_combinations(original))
>>> [(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4), (0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3), (0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4), (0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2), (0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3), (0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2), (0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5), (0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5), (0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.4), (0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.4), (0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4), (0, 0.2 ...
```

Comment: Thanks, the permutation part applies to my problem and this leads me into looking into generators :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), however you will have to increase the size of combinations until you reach the length of the dataset.

```
>>> input_list = [0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5]
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> valid_combinations = []
>>> for comb_length in range(1,len(input_list)+1):
    possible_combinations = combinations(input_list,comb_length)
    for comb in possible_combinations:
        if sum(comb) ==1:
            valid_combinations.append(comb)


>>>valid_combinations
[(0.1, 0.4, 0.5), (0.2, 0.3, 0.5), (0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5), (0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5), (0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4), (0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4)]
```

Read your requirements and updated to have combinations `==1`, not `<= 1`.

**Note** -- if your dataset for input is very large, you will need a better algorithm as this is bruteforce.

Comment: Thanks that is way cleaner than my mess!

Comment: you could use a generator to prevent using up too much memory at the same time (see my answer)